# Optimal way to connect metadata API on another instance via JS

Tags: managed-package, force.com-sites, metadata-api

Basic setup:

1. subscriber is on a Force.com Site page NOT on their intance
2. Have all the necessary oAuth and identity responses using a connected app

What I am trying to do is:

> On click of a button, access subscriber metadata API (open to other options) to upgrade a package

I have tried the following:

1. JS using XHR to send the request but I get

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Adding to the CORS in customer instance is not an option even if it would work.

2. I have tried sending the HTTP Request in apex but get the remote site setting issue. If the remote site exists the works. I guess I could pragmatically use JS to add the remote site on auth but it would require several more requests to login to the main org the site is on to update remote site settings then a request to delete on unload. Rather not do this
3. Push Upgrade API - not an option for us currently.
4. tried to use the [login | test] endpoint but I got (as expected since it was not the proper way to do it lol)

> Destination URL not reset. The URL returned from login must be set in the SforceService

So the questions:

Given the above, is there a better way than #2 to access a subscriber metadata api from a sites page located on the provider force.com site. Ideally a simple JS call to their instance would be bet but I cannot see how to do it due to cross domain.

Will jsForce face same issues? I believe it will so have not tried it yet.

Partner WSDL would have same limitations on the remote site setting as well correct?

Remember, the subscriber as used oAuth to authenticate to their org via the connected app and the identity response has been obtained. (via [login | test].salesforce.com which is a single remote site setting)

Comment: https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi is this helpful

Comment: This requires a remote site setting to be created for each customer

Comment: Can't we create a remote site using metadata call to make it dynamic?

Comment: I would have to create one in our org for every customer that hits the page and remove it on unload. As outlined in the question this gets messy and looking for better option than #2